# How to filter by date if it is within a range of 2 days from a different date?

Tags: python, date

I've got date frame containing two events. The first event is a transaction and the second is an email. Each event has a time frame.  I have to show only those emails that were received within 2 days of the transaction.

The data was downloaded from SQL server, but I do not know how to filter it in such a way in SQL (or if it is even possible).

Comment: you must add some data to your question as well as results examples

Comment: What's a "date frame"?

Comment: spelling mistake - data frame two ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an SQL table

```
TABLE EVENTS
   event_id NUMERIC,
   event_type VARCHAR,
   event_time DATETIME
```

you could use an SQL query along the following lines to get all `(transaction, email)`- pairs that fulfill your requirement:

```
SELECT email.event_id, 
       email.event_time, 
       transaction.event_id, 
       transaction.event_time
FROM EVENTS email JOIN
     EVENTS transaction ON 
         (DATEDIFF(day, transaction.event_time, email.event_time) BETWEEN 0 AND 2)
```

In case you wanted to do it in `pandas`, you could apply a similar logic.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I will try to show the answer to help other people. You need a mock table that has the two columns to create the dataframe needed to filter the duration.

First

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DataFrame containing two events.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TransEvent': ['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-04','2013-01-03'],#transaction
    'EmailEvent': ['2013-01-11', '2013-02-02', '2013-01-06','2013-01-04'] #email
})
df['TransEvent'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TransEvent'], errors='coerce')#convert to Dates
df['EmailEvent'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EmailEvent'], errors='coerce')

df['DurationDays'] =  df.EmailEvent - df.TransEvent
df[['TransEvent','EmailEvent','DurationDays']]
```

Result

```
TransEvent  EmailEvent  DurationDays
0   2013-01-01  2013-01-11  10 days
1   2013-01-02  2013-02-02  31 days
2   2013-01-04  2013-01-06  2 days
3   2013-01-03  2013-01-04  1 days
```

so we are only interested in cases where duration is <= 2 days.

```
#show only those emails that were received within 2 days of the transaction.
df[df['DurationDays']<= pd.Timedelta(2,'D')]
```

Final Answer

```
EmailEvent  TransEvent  DurationDays
2   2013-01-06  2013-01-04  2 days
3   2013-01-04  2013-01-03  1 days
```

Let me know if it works.